# console text written over plymouth splash screen

Tags: raspbian-stretch, plymouth

I have two RPi3s with Raspbian Stretch - one with RS Full and one with RS Lite. I have enabled autologin and our custom plymouth splash screen with "splash quiet" in /boot/cmdline.txt.

Now I want to do same behaviour on RS Lite. I installed X server and Plymouth, added same settings in /boot/cmdline.txt. Everything works ok except one thing - when boot splash appears, the "autologin" message + MOTD is written over this plymouth screen. This does not happen on the other RPi.

Also, I can notice that on RPi "full" boot console is on tty1 but X server starts on tty2. RPi "lite" starts everything on tty1.

Is there any specific settings that could influence this behaviour and I forgot about it? Why RPi "lite" displays the console output over the splash screen, but the other RPi does not?

Comment: I take it the cmdline and config files are identical (apart from obvious differences required)

Comment: Yes, both are identical.

Comment: Have you run [plymouth-set-default-theme YourThemeName](https://www.mankier.com/1/plymouth-set-default-theme) on the "Lite"?

Comment: Of course. But I finally find the main difference. RS "Full" executes X server via "sudo startx pi&" in /etc/rc.local, but I configured RS "Lite" to execute X server via "startx" in ~/.bash_profile. And rc.local seems to start Xserver on tty2 just before MOTD appears (so the described effect is not visible), while bash_profile starts Xserver on tty1 after MOTD.